# Should we allow questions that blatantly pertain to defrauding another website?

Tags: support, ethics, legal

Note that this question was closed as a duplicate of a ***later*** question. (I did my research before posting.)

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23799198/331508) was opened asking for help vote-spamming a third-party website.
The thing is that the results of this vote will be used to [award valuable prizes](https://2014.bringyourbaygame.com/prizes).

Should we even allow questions that seek to violate [another site's TOS](https://2014.bringyourbaygame.com/official-rules)?  Or to commit what is a crime in almost every jurisdiction?
If so, what's the best way to close them?

Otherwise, the question is a near duplicate and could be answered in 15 minutes of honest searching on Stack Overflow.

---

PS:  So far, I haven't found [likely terms in the SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=defraud).

## Update2 (2018-06-02):

From the (now redacted) [**Stack Exchange Terms of Service, section 3 (e)**, before approximately Feb 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20180206143309/https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service):

It said that it is forbidden to post...

> (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or **other computer programming routine or engine** that is intended **to** damage, **detrimentally interfere** with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate **any system, data or information**,

This would seem to apply to the linked question.

Comment: [What to do with a question about how to do something that violates 3rd party Terms of Service?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139024)

Comment: *Stack Overflow/Exchange has no place in the agreement between two other parties, and has no responsibilty to police that agreement. In fact, it might be a bad idea for SE to start trying to do such policing, because someone could decide they are liable for episodes that they missed.*

Comment: Thanks for the link, @MartijnPieters, I was still searching for terms like fraud.  This case is a little more serious than just a TOS violation.  There's actual fraud with money on the line.

Comment: The question should be evaluated on its merits alone; we can not and do not enforce other people's TOS. Where does it end? What if I start a web site whose TOS state people can't write quality code? It shouldn't be a problem, though: fraud-y questions get downvoted quickly

Comment: Stack Overflow is about spreading knowledge. People want to know how to click on a button using javascript. That is an acceptable question (and has been asked already!). Asking how to press a button and do it every 2 hours so he can win an "internetcontest" are: basically 2 questions, too broad (c++ and greasemonkey tags?) and shows no research effort. Flag it and downvote it. If we only accept "pure knowledge" questions then we don't have to worry about ethics :)

Comment: @BrockAdams: It is *still* third-party agreements that's are at stake here. It doesn't matter if it is a TOS, NDA, contract or student code of honour, or what the consequences are of breaking those agreements.

Comment: Also, that linked answer was just someone's opinion.  By the votes, nowhere near a consensus.  Nor was it any kind of authoritative answer.

Comment: @Brock, *crime* may be too strong here. Best case, it will pass the message that the voting model they use can be easily abused, and they will change it. There's no harm asking how to to get into your house when your front door is already wide open.

Comment: @BrockAdams: **Then don't answer**. It doesn't make the question *off topic* though. And in what jurisdiction is it a crime? Does it apply to someone from Asia answering if the contest is in Africa?

Comment: If anything, if the "fraud" bothers you that much, edit the question to a point where it simply asks for the automated clicking of a button at a regular interval.

Comment: @BrockAdams: It's the same answer as for NDAs: [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465)

Comment: Okay put it another way. I (or any honest thinker) can see that this is a wrong practice without needing to see any TOS.  What the poster of that question is trying to do is no different that trying to sneak counterfeit raffle tickets into the the elementary school prize contest.  I'm frankly stunned that so many can not instantly see that that is wrong.  No TOS needed.

Comment: @BrockAdams that is something the website needs to handle though. That's not up to us. If the question is technically fine, there's no need to close it. You could downvote it if you so desire, but it doesn't fit any of the close reasons.

Comment: @BrockAdams: nowhere do I say that I *personally* think trying to break a contest is fine. But we cannot, as a policy, police this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I don't agree in cases where the poster is so blatant about it.  I understand the potential liability argument made in the linked answer -- made by neither a lawyer nor a Stack Exchange representative (and not receiving many votes) -- I don't agree with it.  Fear of what some shysters *might* do is no reason to not do the right thing!

Comment: @BrockAdams: Shog9 is a SE representative and has posted on the NDA FAQ page. Note that there is no opposite statement from SE **either**. Further note that Stack Exchange has been around for +5 years and has seen a fair share of such blatant posts. There is a fair amount of discussion on the subject on MetaSE on the subject, and if there is no statement of the kind you are looking for then that's because *that would be redundant*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, actually, thanks to Shog9's posts, I found that SE has in fact posted exactly what I'm looking for; it's right in the TOS.  See the updated Q.

Comment: I don't see how SO would benefit in any way from helping someone damage another website. If anything, it would damage the reputation of SO.

Comment: @Jordy poor security is a poor excuse for malevolence.

Comment: @Jordy, I highlighted the wrong phrase.  It certainly "detrimentally interferes" with the vote that site is trying to run.

Comment: How exactly is voting every two hours abusive/defrauding/illegal if the site **allows** you to vote every two hours?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, First, the linked-Q-asker lied. Read the actual terms (linked in my Q above). Second that TOS just attempts to codify the ethical and legal principle of one (live) voter periodically voting within the limits of his/her will power and motivation. NOT 20 counterfeit bots, trying to defraud their system.  Just because it's easy doesn't mean it's not a crime.

Comment: @CoderDojo: Stack Overflow helped build [the Silk Road dark web drug trafficking website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/did-the-stack-exchange-staff-members-assist-in-the-apprehension-of-ross-ulbricht); when it came out it didn't damage Stack's reputation either.

Comment: @Cupcake, WTF?  If anything, that question is a duplicate of this one.  The accepted answer, by a diamond-mod, even says so! Also, I wasn't looking for a discussion, I was looking for an official SE response ([support]).

Comment: @BrockAdams calm down please. I chose the other question because it has a better title. You're welcome to disagree, and of course reopen in the event that this does get closed.

Comment: @Cupcake, also note that the answer here is semi-official, from an SE representative.  The answer there is just another Mod's opinion (although a respected mod).

Comment: The Terms of Service appear to have removed the cited clause.

Comment: @faintsignal, so it did. And even power users may not be aware of Shog's "Official" answer below.  I wonder how SE is protected from liability now that the TOS permits harmful content.  (That Indemnification clause would not stand up in court.)  All the big companies are redacting their "Do no evil" clauses.  Should we be worried?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Questions regarding things that are illegal are disallowed. Questions that seek help in damaging people or property are disallowed.

Terms of Services are not laws, however. They're agreements between people/organizations. Unless you're one of those people, they don't apply to you. Whether or not violating them is damaging to others is subjective: the most common case where this arises involves those wretched Apple NDAs, which even Apple's devs admit are a sick joke.

The motives of the author of the question you posted seem rather less pure, of course. That said, the question is crap and (as you noted) a duplicate - so I don't see any particular need to look for *more* problems with it. Downvote & close as usual.