# How do we handle questions that are potentially or blatantly illegal or malicious?

Tags: discussion, legal, ethics

Recently, I came across a question where it seemed like the user wanted help removing the trial message from a piece of trial software (get around purchasing it legitimately).  This got me thinking more generically about whether or not such questions should be downvoted or flagged / which flag to use.  Specifically questions (or answers) pertaining to things like:

- Remove trial limitations
- Circumvent license keys
- Bypass authentication
- Suppressing licensing / copyright messages

**My Question:** Is there a 'recommended' way to deal with posts that ask questions or give answers attempting to do something potentially illegal (or at the very least immoral)?

For context, the question that raised this issue in my mind initially is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124958/how-to-remove-menucool-ddmenu-trial-version-from-jscript

---

While the question here: [What is the policy on questions that ask how to crack passwords?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256139/what-is-the-policy-on-questions-that-ask-how-to-crack-passwords) is related, it addresses a completely different area of legality.  Cracking passwords may lead to the FBI knocking on your door, where violating a license agreement / bypassing a payment mechanism for software will get corporate lawyers sending you cease and desist letters (to begin with).  My question is more broad and addresses what should be done in potentially gray areas as opposed to specifically about password cracking, malware, or other malicious coding practices.

This question: [Should we allow questions that blatantly pertain to defrauding another website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255756/should-we-allow-questions-that-blatantly-pertain-to-defrauding-another-website) has very little to do with software development and more with a type of click-spamming, though it is similar in nature it is a very different question.

Comment: For the specific question you posted, I would (read: have) vote to close it. It's not a true question, and there are a lot of holes in what is wanted.

Comment: You'll find a number of related questions under the [meta-tag:ethics] tag, such as [Should we allow questions that blatantly pertain to defrauding another website?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255756/456814).

Comment: @random While I agree that question is related, my question is different in that it is specific to the usage of third party software in development and software licensing terms as opposed to developing potentially malicious code.  As a side note, password cracking (in the case of penetration testing / security analysis) can have a legitimate use, where violating license agreements will rarely if ever have a legitimate use.

Comment: Ask the OP how much it's worth to him to keep quiet.

Comment: Related: [What is the policy on questions that ask how to crack passwords?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256139/456814).

Comment: See also [Dealing with questions of nefarious intent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3528).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Your question here is not materially different than the click-fraud one, and the answer is essentially the same: close if it's crap, or if it clearly intends to harm someone else.  Questions that clearly seek to defraud or otherwise harm are not allowed here.

There is, of course, nothing to prevent people from asking general questions about a technique such as injecting code into a DLL.  The question you have to ask yourself is this: does the technique *have any possible legitimate uses?*  If you're a white hat, the answer is often "yes," because understanding the technique can help you defend yourself against black hats.

In any case, if the question doesn't appear to have any redeeming value (even to white hats), or targets a specific individual or organization (help me hack this website), then vote to close accordingly.

Comment: You may want to have a moderator discussion about this.  I flagged a question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110345/hide-the-balance-reduction-popup-form-the-telecom-company-on-sending-sms-from-an where he said he was writing a malicious program in his question (check the edit history).  The moderator ignored my flag.  I ended up abusing gold powers to 1 vote close it.

Comment: @GabeSechan: That guy is question-blocked.  I don't think you'll have to worry about him anymore.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan: doesn’t sound like “abusing” to me. Rather, it seems to be an implementation of the “the community is the moderator” mantra of SO.

Comment: I've tried flagging questions twice when they contained requests for help on blatantly illegal activity (typically installing game cracks).  Both times my flags were "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".  This puzzles me, as removing illegal questions seems like something that moderators should intervene in.  (And I've seen another one today, but I'm now discouraged from flagging it.)

Comment: @Miral: Moderators are not law enforcement. Some mods will not police these things.  You're certainly free to cast a flag; declined flags are not that big of a deal unless you get many of them.

Comment: I ran into a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905207/how-to-make-any-auto-extract-file-that-doesnt-show-its-window) recently where the OP basically admits that they're planning on using it for a malicious purpose. (What makes it even worse is that the question is also "gimme teh codez"). Can questions like this be mod-flagged or flagged as rude/abusive? Or should we just downvote and vote to close it?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Terrible question which can be closed on the usual grounds.  No cogitation about maliciousness necessary.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't see deleted questions yet - what close reason did you end up choosing? Too broad, OT for "gimme teh codez," or OT for being malicious?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: I just deleted it without closing.

Comment: *then vote to close accordingly* - how?

Comment: @MrUpsidown _Vote to close accordingly_ would be a vote to close based on the reason it should be closed. If it is one of the category of questions "not allowed here" then the close reason would be off-topic. If the question is trash, and intent is slightly questionable, use the other close reasons, likely candidates would be low quality and unclear. Reserve the use of flags for exactly what they are labeled. Only use the spam flag if the post _is_ spam, and the rude/abusive flag if it _is_ rude or abusive. Mod flag is to have mods do what users cannot - and closing a bad question users can do