# How to deal with potentially malcious or rather useless links in a question?

Tags: discussion, external-links, security

Various questions and answers on *SO* contain links that I would consider useless, or even potentially dangerous. (This is especially true for questions that deal with front-end web development.)

There have been discussions on Meta about entire [malicious questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou), but this a bit different: A question may be legitimate; even the link at the time of posting. But it could replaced by something malicious after a period of time. If the entire question is bad, it can simply be removed. But a legitimate (or even: good) question with a useless or potentially malicious link is a bit more delicate.

For example, every day, there are dozens of questions of the type: “Here's my project, please tell me what's wrong with it”. In this question → [Tooltip with toggle div click to open, and then click to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855893/tooltip-with-toggle-div-clcik-to-open-and-then-click-to-close) the author even posts a link to a ZIP file.

I'm also afraid that links to random external pages could be exploited for spamming. For example, a bad user could post a question with a seemingly legitimate link, and after some weeks, replace the resource which the link points to with something malicious.

This would be very hard to detect for the SO community (at least it has a good chance of going undetected), while people reaching the question via a search engine might fall for the trap.

Of course, one would ask the author to post some relevant code on *SO* and remove the link. But I feel it would be wrong to remove such links through an edit. Because: What should I insert instead, without making the question completely useless?

So, my question would be: What's the policy on links that don't point to a useful ressource? “Useful resource” would be defined as a webpage which gives a deeper insight into the topic or nature of the problem (such as a tutorial or Howto), or a webpage that demonstrates the problem in an isolated example, on a *trusted* site (e.g. JSfiddle).

Comment: I saw that one, but I think this case is different. A question may be legitimate; even the link at the time of posting. But it could replaced by something malicious after a period of time. If the entire question is bad, it can simply be removed. But a legitimate (or even: good) question with a useless or potentially malicious link is a bit more delicate.

Comment: As the question is useless without the external content, just vote/flag for closure: off-topi -> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ok, but I would like to give the author the chance to improve the post. In most situations, they don't have a bad intention, and are willing to improve. Therefore, I don't immediately flag, but leave a comment. But if there's no response by the author, one will usually loose track of the post. So it's not unlikely that such links slip though.

Comment: @lxg: Just flag/vote directly (You might comment and wait 5 minutes if you want to leave it open that long). The reopen-queue is efficient, the close-vote-queue not so much.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @gnat: thanks, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this:

If a question contains a link to a download, edit it out. Questions on StackOverflow should be self-contained, with code that allows you to reproduce the issue in the question itself. No-one should ever need to download that file, and if it is required, the question needs to be closed until it is improved.

As for any other link, I would see no harm in leaving it, as long as the question can be answered/understood without clicking the link. In particular with .htaccess questions I am sometimes glad people link to their own site, just so I can reproduce all the madness they came up with myself.