# Found an answer that includes license keys

Tags: discussion, answers

Reviewing first posts, I came across an answer that included license keys for copyrighted software. I couldn't find a specific policy against that, but I flagged it and selected "other" as the reason, gave details, etc.

Did I just miss that policy, or is it covered under some broader policy?

The poster was attempting to answer the question, albeit poorly. Was there a more appropriate flag to use?

Comment: Another option is to edit the answer, and remove the license keys.

Comment: Slightly related, even though it deals with a different scenario: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou.

Comment: @RetoKoradi OK. That makes sense. I'll do that too. Thanks.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes, that's very related. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have asked a variant of this question before as a similar circumstance arose for me. In the situation I encountered the OP provided username and password credentials to an admin account in a comment.

I think the correct course of action is to edit the post, changing the API key (or password, ouath token, private key, ...), then flag as "other", explain the situation and ask that the revision history be removed.

I feel that it is in everyone's best interest for Stack Overflow to try to mitigate these kinds of security disclosures. For obvious reasons.