# Closing a question that may be asking to break the law?

Tags: support, flags

I have seen here on META that questions that ask how to potentially break laws, but not for purposes of white hatting, should be closed. But when I tried to mark [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633144/can-i-hit-an-ip-with-curl-containing-server-credentials-of-login-to-bypass-serve) closed, I was not sure which option to choose as to the reason...

- **duplicate of...** This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
- **off-topic because...** This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.
- **unclear what you're asking** Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
- **too broad** There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
- **primarily opinion-based** Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

## Which is most appropriate?

I deleted my answer, which explained how to curl with Basic Auth, his response was this...

> "Thats fine but i dont know about the popup form fields name as well as its action? Only thing i know is ip address. Will it work if i hit that ip using your curl code?" – user3769872.

Basically, he doesn't know the user/pass but would like to get in.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou

Comment: Ah, with the nuances it's reasonable.

Comment: I was willing to help until he basically admitted he was just trying to get into somewhere he didn't have a user/pass for. And he was definitely not pen testing.

Comment: I downvote, closevote and leave a comment on such posts that I see.  Others can be future defendants in some hacking-victim lawsuit if they wish, I do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a question from someone who tries to break the law.

I see a user who doesn't understand how http calls work and how the different authentication schemes should be used. They managed to find some reasonable tags but are mostly clueless, indicated by the lack of any examples of what they tried, error messages etc.

A close vote as unclear what you're asking (or too broad) is the best we can do and a downvote.

On the legal part: we can't judge if things the OP wants is legal or not. It might be legal in my country, but not in that of the OP. I like to give the example of a question about unbreakable encryption. I might use that to keep my evil plans hidden from the government, or to protect my privacy as an European citizen.

Comment: I deleted my answer, which explained how to curl with Basic Auth, his response was this... "Thats fine but i dont know about the popup form fields name as well as its action? Only thing i know is ip address. Will it work if i hit that ip using your curl code?" –  user3769872. Basically, he doesn't know the user/pass but would like to get in.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your answer and that comment. That is why I think this user doesn't know what problem they try to solve, Maybe the are hitting a windows box with integrated security. That OP is lost in some technical challenge, not a hacker.

Comment: So what is the best way to approach this post?

Comment: Close it and wait for the OP to add the details needed.