# How to flag people asking for help to violate another site's Terms of Service?

Tags: discussion, ethics

On Stack Overflow, one user [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543826/how-to-hide-youtube-all-branding-including-water-mark-when-embed) to help him violating Youtube's Terms of Service.

> [image]

This question should be closed.

Based on which criteria can I flag it?

Comment: Related, but different: [Unethical, possibly illegal assistance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329321/unethical-possibly-illegal-assistance)

Comment: The post at present was too broad, and was hence closed. Are you asking this question in a general sense or related to the [meta-tag:specific-question] only?

Comment: @BhargavRao I'll keep refreshing that question until I see your deletion action ;)

Comment: @Maroun, Hey no need to refresh, You'll get that purple banner across the post. ;) ... But on a serious note, Once a post has come to meta, I feel that it's better to wait till we get a consensus before jumping on the post and deleting it. (I know that the question is quite delete worthy, But I'd like to wait for sometime more).

Comment: @BhargavRao "Are you asking this question in a general sense or related to the specific-question only?"---what did you mean? I m asking for this question and in future for this type of question.

Comment: The one you mention is a better duplicate.

Comment: @BhargavRao ok I read those two link,but still there is no specific criteria to face this problem.i think it should be

Comment: No, there shouldn't be. We can't enforce all laws, or all terms of service, that exist - nor should we. If a question is asking for something openly and obviously illegal, the community will vote it down on gut feeling alone, and normally there is some other close reason that fits the situation.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a typo of "without"? Granted, the task almost certainly can't be accomplished without violating the terms, but adding an explicit request to help violate the TOS seems... unlikely.

Comment: The biggest issue I see with this is that you cannot ethically run your site by shaming people asking for help who are violating an ethical reasoning to you. Ethical is a very subjective term and varies depending on who you are referring to and what the instance is.

If this does violate rules and you don't want the site to get in trouble for aiding these acts, that is a different story and understandable. It should be stated where in the TOS this is for objective arguments. 

TLDR: For the sake of professionalism we need to use better reasoning than something being unethical (to you).

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312587/792066

Answer (score 29):

This particular question is "Too Broad". It's asking how to do something, and doesn't even show an attempt at *thinking* about a solution. Let alone a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.

In general, if a post is asking for things that are blatantly illegal, or for things that could hurt other people, you can use a custom moderator flag and explain the situation.

Asking for help with violating the TOS of another site... it's not something we encourage, but it's not always off-topic. Such questions can also be useful to white-hats defending those sites. Each of these questions needs to be judged on their own merit.

(If your moral compass says "THIS IS BAD!!", use a custom moderator flag.)

Copying a moderator's relevant comment into the answer for visibility:

> Moderators generally do not accept flags alleging a post might be asking something illegal or violating the terms of service of another site, etc.. We are not legal arbiters, nor do we judge posts based on moral compasses.

Comment: Can you edit this so it reads "illegal in the United States" please, as that is the country of hosting. Moreover, "illegal" does not mean very much without specifying a jurisdiction of some kind - we often forget that things are not _intrinsically_ illegal.

Comment: I'll point out that if you flag a moderator asking us to remove or close something solely because it violates a third party's terms and conditions, we most likely will decline that flag. Moderators cannot be a judge of some other site's terms and conditions, and we're ill-equipped to judge legal matters in general. If people at the site in question have a real problem with a post, they can contact SE staff directly.

Comment: @BradLarson "we're ill-equipped to judge legal matters in general" and yet https://stackexchange.com/legal explicitly says "engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited". You can't have it both ways ... ;p

Comment: @DavidPostill - Just because Stack Exchange has the *right* to toss someone off the site for committing illegal activities does not mean that moderators or even the site itself are *required* to search out and take action against anyone who might be doing so. Also: "To the fullest extent allowed by law, Stack Exchange disclaims any liability or responsibility for the accuracy, reliability, availability, completeness, legality or operability of the material or services provided on this Network."

Comment: I have to re-iterate this: **Moderators generally do not accept flags alleging a post might be asking something illegal or violating the terms of service of another site, etc.**. We are not legal arbiters, nor do we judge posts based on moral compasses.

Answer (score 21):

We would probably need a legal expert to decide whether the existence of a third-party's Terms of Service has the power to bind anyone who uses that service. Moreover, we would need a legal view of that from country to country, since this judgement is likely to vary from one jurisdiction to another. We might also need someone to decide if the advocation of a ToS violation would harm Stack Overflow by virtue of their hosting it.

So, as you can see, it is rather complex, and since we are not lawyers, we should do this as little as possible. There are plenty of reasonable use-cases for technology that violates at least one ToS, and not all ToS documents are reasonable.

My own view is that a ToS is a contract which I often won't read or actively consent to, and there are many companies who, out of excessive legal caution, will attempt to bind users in a restrictive tar of legalese. A lot of this is lawyers creating work for lawyers, and I am not in favour of it. It is a great pity that only a few web services pride themselves on a short, readable ToS, and that it is so rare that they feel able to shout about it.

In short: don't flag these at all.

Comment: A million times this. I meant to write something like this but had more pressing things to do. It costs very little to shove things into a ToS that may not be enforceable. There's no general penalty for putting non-enforceable clauses in a ToS. A company can threaten legal recourse only to drop the case at the 11th hour. Or the case could go to court and the clause be found to have no legal force. (Example: In the US, TOS clauses that aimed to prevent consumers from writing negative reviews have been recently been rendered void by the Consumer Review Freedom Act.)