# Is there a rule of conduct to handle supposedly ill-minded requests?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, offensive

I've been following a [post that was asking to spoof an email sender.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392314/how-to-change-the-email-senders-name-from-a-contact-form-using-php)
OP was asking for details on how to spoof a sender's address. Downvotes were pouring in, while a lively communication in the comments section took place. I flagged the post for deletion, but as you know this is a process that might take a while. So my question is, is there a code of conduct to handle requests that seem to give offense to a netiquette or otherwise appear to be ill-minded, and how to handle such requests by the community?

Comment: related, if not a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou

Comment: Note, this isn't nearly as malicious as yacc is making it out to be. Adding an alias to the email's "FROM" header is quite common.

Answer (score 19):

If you feel a question is in violation of SO's rules, flag it.

If anything, you ***don't*** do this:

> *"If I could I'd stop this piece of crap of a request at once. @AbhishekD"* – yacc 22 mins ago

Comments like that are in violation of SO's "Be nice" policy, and will be flagged.